# How can I compare numbers when the language only has "loop while not zero"?

Tags: programming-languages

As a hobby project I have been developing an IDE for [Chef](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/chef.html), an esoteric programming language. While writing various test programs in Chef I've realised that implementing a simple sort algorithm, or even comparing two integers to see which one is greater, is a major challenge when the only compare-and-branch statement in the language is a loop which will repeat while a number is non zero. For example:

```
Dissolve the sugar.         <-- execute loop if value of 'sugar' is non zero
  Add flour to mixing bowl. <-- add value of 'flour' into mixing bowl
  Set aside.                <-- break out of the loop
Stir until dissolved.       <-- mark the end of the loop
```

I do have a working solution to compare two integers in Chef, but it is 40 lines long!

Here is an equivalent of my approach in Java, which most will find more readable than the Chef code I wrote :-)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int first = 100;
    int second = 200;

    int looper = 1;
    int tester;

    int difference = first - second;
    int inverse = difference * -1;
    while (looper != 0) {
        difference -= 1;
        inverse -= 1;

        tester = 1;
        while (difference != 0) {
            tester--;
            break;
        }
        while (tester != 0) {
            System.out.println("First is bigger");
            exit(1);
        }
        tester = 1;
        while (inverse != 0) {
            tester--;
            break;
        }
        while (tester != 0) {
            System.out.println("Second is bigger");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, what's the best way of comparing two numbers when all I have is a loop while non-zero ?

Comment: I doubt that you can compare by having only while loop, you're definitely using other operations (addition, subtraction, etc), can you use bitwise operators?

Comment: @IłyaBursov No bitwise operators, I'm afraid. You can see the full language spec above (it's linked at the top of my post click on 'Chef') but basically the loop-while-not-zero is the only comparison/branch instruction. Other than that, there are the standard arithmetic operations `+ - * /` and stack push/pop instructions, plus read and write to stdin/out.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing I could think about is somehow to round numbers so you can decrement them until one is zero. This is the way it is done in brainfuck which has quite the same problem but does not have non-integer numbers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).